# How to sort a field many2one

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I need sort a combo box in asc o desc in ODOO 8.

This is my combo box.
[This is my combo box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnQW2.jpg)

Help me please, thaks.

Answer (score 3):

In your xml `context="{'order_display': 'name desc' }"` for descending order. Try asc in it.

Comment: Do you know of any documentation about this feature?